# Perl LWP:UserAgent how to I add headers?

Tags: perl, curl, lwp

I'm a new perl programmer trying to convert a curl request into a Perl script get using LWP:UserAgent.

The curl request example is:

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Postman-Token: eb3955f1-a7b5-65d7-f5c0-808c7aba6cef" "https://10.51.10.26/10/download?startTime=1461698250&endTime=1461698252&cNat=True&cNatShowDst=True&tuplesFile=True&summarizeTuples=False"
```

And my PERL equivalent:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $url = 'https://10.51.10.26/10/download';
my @headers = (
   "startTime" => $queryStart, 
   "endTime" => $queryEnd, 
   "cNat" => "True", 
   "cNatShowDst" => "False", 
   "tuplesFile" => "False", 
   "summarizeTuples" => "False",
   "Authorization" => "Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4",
   "Cache-Control" => "no-cache", 
   "Postman-Token" => "eb3955f1-a7b5-65d7-f5c0-808c7aba6cef", 
);
```

Results in - `HTTP::Response=HASH(0x27884bc)`

Is this the correct way of adding headers?

Comment: You are not showing your full code. The code does not produce that output as there is no sending happening. See http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/perl/983/debug-output#t=201607270944292058065 to learn how to output objects so you understand them.

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how to mark a question as resolved. :)

Answer (score 8):

If you want to do a GET request with custom headers with LWP::UserAgent, you can put them into the `$ua->get()` call in the way [the documentation describes](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent#ua-get-url-field_name-value).

> This method will dispatch a GET request on the given $url. Further arguments can be given to initialize the headers of the request. These are given as separate name/value pairs. The return value is a response object. See HTTP::Response for a description of the interface it provides.

Your example is missing the part where you are sending the request, so it's hard to tell what you are doing.

Your `@headers` array contains both headers and URL params. That's not going to do what you expect. If you want to construct the URL and the headers like this, you need a different approach.

Use the [URI module](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI#uri-query_form) to create the URI programmatically, then use LWP::UA's `get` to send it including the headers.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use URI;

my $uri = URI->new('https://10.51.10.26/10/download');
$uri->query_form(
    "startTime"       => $queryStart, # these two need 
    "endTime"         => $queryEnd,   # to be set above
    "cNat"            => "True", 
    "cNatShowDst"     => "False", 
    "tuplesFile"      => "False", 
    "summarizeTuples" => "False",   
);

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $res = $ua->get(
    $uri,
    "Authorization" => "Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4",
    "Cache-Control" => "no-cache", 
    "Postman-Token" => "eb3955f1-a7b5-65d7-f5c0-808c7aba6cef", 
);

if ($res->is_success) {
    # do stuff with content
} else {
    # request failed
}
```

To output the full HTTP::Response object, use [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper).

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper $res;
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive and quick response. I'll give that a spin.

Answer (score 4):

Your Perl code doesn't result in the HTTP::Response object that you show. It can't possibly do that as your code doesn't actually make a request.

Putting new headers in an array called `@headers` isn't going to achieve anything useful either. You need to attach those headers to the request in some way.

LWP includes [a useful tutorial](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/libwww-perl/lwptut.pod). It would be a good idea to read that before trying to do too much with the tools. In particular, it includes a section entitled [Adding Other HTTP Request Headers](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/libwww-perl/lwptut.pod#Adding-Other-HTTP-Request-Headers) which says:

> The most commonly used syntax for requests is `$response = $browser->get($url)`,
>   but in truth, you can add extra HTTP header lines
>   to the request by adding a list of key-value pairs after the URL, like
>   so:
>
> ```
> $response = $browser->get( $url, $key1, $value1, $key2, $value2, ... );
> ```
>
> For example, here's how to send some more Netscape-like headers, in
>   case you're dealing with a site that would otherwise reject your
>   request:
>
> ```
> my @ns_headers = (
>   'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/4.76 [en] (Win98; U)', 
>   'Accept' => 'image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg,image/png, */*',
>   'Accept-Charset' => 'iso-8859-1,*,utf-8', 
>   'Accept-Language' => 'en-US', );
>
> ...
>
> $response = $browser->get($url, @ns_headers);
> ```
>
> If you weren't reusing that array, you could just go ahead and do
>   this:
>
> ```
> $response = $browser->get($url,
>   'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/4.76 [en] (Win98; U)',
>   'Accept' => 'image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, image/png, */*',
>   'Accept-Charset' => 'iso-8859-1,*,utf-8',
>   'Accept-Language' => 'en-US',
> );
> ```
>
> If you were only ever changing the 'User-Agent' line, you could just
>   change the `$browser` object's default line from "libwww-perl/5.65" (or
>   the like) to whatever you like, using the LWP::UserAgent agent method:
>
> ```
> $browser->agent('Mozilla/4.76 [en] (Win98; U)');
> ```

It's worth pointing out that [LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent) also has a `default_headers()` method which allows you to define headers which are added to every request made by that useragent.

People have put a lot of effort into creating a lot of useful documentation for Perl tools. That effort is rather wasted if people don't read it.